# How do I format a JSON feed to be used with FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

In FullCalendar you can pull events from a JSON feed, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's my attempt at creating that feed:

```
{
events: [
{
    title: 'All Day Event',
    start: new Date(y, m, 1)
},
{
    title: 'Long Event',
    start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
    end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
},
{
    title: 'Meeting',
    start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
    allDay: false
},
{
    title: 'Lunch',
    start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
    end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
    allDay: false
},
{
    title: 'Birthday Party',
    start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
    end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
    allDay: false
}
]
}
```

Comment: Please paste more code.

Comment: That isin't valid [JSON](http://www.json.org/) at all. [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Your JSON is correct see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcallaghan2001/vqqk4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to stringify that object first (creating a valid JSON obj).

```
var obj = // the obj you provided above,
    jsonObj = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Now you can feed FullCalendar with the jsonObj above.

Answer (score 0):

Date for events must be in `ISO 8601` format, something like this `2013-07-09T19:10:00-04:00`.
You can use fullcalendar `$.fullCalendar.formatDate(from, format);` to convert date and time.